# Swift: problems when retrieving file's icon on Mac

Tags: swift, macos

I use the following code to retrieve icon of files or folders. Then show them in a menu. My problem is: some files, the icon is not displayed (for example `.txt` file). Icons of folders and some other files are still displayed. What is possible cause of this problem?

```
// menuItem.Title: display name for file/folder
// menuItem.Content: full path of file/url


let menuItem = NSMenuItem(title: item.Title, action: #selector(AppDelegate.openLocal(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")

let requiredAttributes = [URLResourceKey.effectiveIconKey]


if let enumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: URL(fileURLWithPath: item.Content), includingPropertiesForKeys: requiredAttributes, options: [.skipsHiddenFiles, .skipsPackageDescendants, .skipsSubdirectoryDescendants], errorHandler: nil) {

    while let url = enumerator.nextObject() as? URL {

        do {
            let properties = try  (url as NSURL).resourceValues(forKeys: requiredAttributes)

            let icon = properties[URLResourceKey.effectiveIconKey] as? NSImage  ?? NSImage()
            menuItem.image = icon

        }
        catch {

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the following code to get the icon for a file. This works pretty reliably:

```
static func getIconForUrl(_ path: String) -> NSImage?
{
    return NSWorkspace.shared.icon(forFile: path)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code is perfect. I found some problem in 'if let enumerator...'